# Is WordPress vulnerable to the httpoxy?

Tags: security

Is WordPress vulnerable to the httpoxy exploit? See https://httpoxy.org/
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I follow the description right the vulnerability refers to PHP applications which read, trust, and use `HTTP_PROXY` environment value (which might be compromised).

From quick search through WordPress core source code I found **no** instances of that value being accessed.

Since WP ships its own HTTP client implementation its also not affected by upstream library issues (such as Guzzle example). Though I think Requests library is being merged into core in near future, but it doesn't seem to be mentioned as vulnerable on that site.

So I would cautiously guess that WordPress *core* is fine about it. Of course extension space is anything goes.

Comment: Related and "funny" as this is a recent issue on the mentioned Requests library: https://github.com/rmccue/Requests/issues/218 . :-)